# How to input a string containing between 1 and 50 characters.(Assembly)

Tags: string, assembly, masm, irvine32, machine-code

```
;This program reverses a string.
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
   aName BYTE "Abraham Lincoln",0
   nameSize = ($ - aName) - 1
.code

main PROC
   ; Push the name on the stack.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L1: movzx eax,aName[esi] ; get character
     push eax ; push on stack
     inc esi
   Loop L1
   ; Pop the name from the stack, in reverse,
   ; and store in the aName array.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L2: pop eax ; get character
     mov aName[esi],al ; store in string
     inc esi
   Loop L2
   ; Display the name.
   mov edx,OFFSET aName
   call Writestring
   call Crlf
   exit
   main ENDP
END main
```

I finished the first part of the problem which was making a Reverse String program but now I need to modify the program so the user can input a string containing between 1 and 50 characters. Im not to sure how to do this and was wondering if someone could help out. This is in assembly language btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ReadString` from `irvine32.lib`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readstring.htm). Therefor you have to change `nameSize` to a variable and to increase the size of `aName`.

I did it for you ;-) :

```
;This program reverses a string.
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
   aName BYTE 51 DUP (?)
   nameSize dd ?
.code

main PROC

   mov  edx, OFFSET aName
   mov  ecx, 50            ;buffer size - 1
   call ReadString
   mov nameSize, eax

   ; Push the name on the stack.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L1: movzx eax,aName[esi] ; get character
     push eax ; push on stack
     inc esi
   Loop L1
   ; Pop the name from the stack, in reverse,
   ; and store in the aName array.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L2: pop eax ; get character
     mov aName[esi],al ; store in string
     inc esi
   Loop L2
   ; Display the name.
   mov edx,OFFSET aName
   call Writestring
   call Crlf
   exit
   main ENDP
END main
```